# How to write an NGINX rewrite which strips out everything from the URL after /filters/

Tags: symfony, nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi

We're running a Symfony application, which has a route of:
domain.tld/main-category/category/

For SEO purposes, they want to include filters in the URL like this:
domain.tld/main-category/category/filters/price:0-100

So basically we want the URL in the browser to remain the same, but in Symfony it should strip out everything after and including /filters/. So the route should remain "domain.tld/main-category/category/".

I tried this which does work, however I need it to work using Symfony routes but could not get it to work.

```
rewrite ^/.*/filters/.* /test.html last;
```

NGINX config:

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php_project:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER: This is a bit of a guess and might not work for you*

PHP applications such as `index.php` often use the `REQUEST_URI` parameter to determine the "route". This is defined within your `fastcgi_params` file as:

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
```

One solution could be to manipulate this value using a [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

For example:

```
map $request_uri $myroute {
    default                      $request_uri;
    ~*^(?<newroute>/.*)/filters/  $newroute;
}
server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php_project:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $myroute;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Note that the `map` must be placed outside of the `server` block.

You do not need to edit the `fastcgi_params` file, simply ensure that the `fastcgi_param` statements appear in the location block **after** the `include` statement.